# Interpreting Camera GPSYaw to Geographic Direction

Tags: gps, direction, bearing, exif

If the GIS SE is not the place for this question, please point me in the right direction.

I have been extracting the geographic information from a number of photographs. This spatial information is stored in the photograph's exif data.

Part of the data I am extracting is the GPSRoll, GPSPitch and GPSYaw.

I am plotting these locations on a Leaflet map and was looking to impart some additional information onto the map using symbology.

I am trying to interpret the GPSYaw values into a direction attribute I can use to either generate a line or change the style of the point to some predetermined symbol. The question I have relates to how do I interpret the values coming out of the GPSYaw field of the exif data.

The values lie within a range of 0 to 180 and 0 to -180. Am I correct in assuming that the postive value relate to a direction relative to north from North, East and South and the negative values are North, West and South?

Or is this too simplistic and the GPSYaw relates to something completely different, or is somehow a combination of the pitch and roll values?

Comment: Do you know what brand the camera is? Do you have access to test? Guessing not. Might have some more assistance at the photography.SE. But doing some general browsing seems like that are not standardized tags, so it might be platform dependent. https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=9738.0

Comment: One of the commentors suggested that GPSYaw is used as GPSImgDirection which is 0-359 instead. https://exiv2.org/tags.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I’ll look into it. I do know the camera type, but do not have access to the camera itself. I’ll check if there are other tags I can see.

Comment: Take 4 pictures with the drone facing north, south, east, and west.  Read the GPSYaw values from those images?  Consider whether the returned values reference true north or magnetic north.  Still, you want the camera yaw right, not the drone's yaw?

Comment: Thank you @GBG. I will use a hybrid of this. The photos are not from a drone, but hand-held Canon EOS. I will try extract the Yaw values that I think would match N, S, E and W and then see where they point.

Comment: Which mode of Canon EOS?

Comment: @Simbamangu its a Canon EOS-1D X Mark II